# How can I visit a family member who's at college?

Tags: virtual-families-2

It's been 6-7 years after the daughter Friana left to go to college and now she's sending the rest of the family an email asking to visit her so as to not "be strangers."

I know for a fact there aren't any cars or stuff like that so my question is this:
how can I visit a family member in college?

Also, when will she come back?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to visit them in college. They only come back to your house when their parents pass away.